# Show a progress bar when executing a task

Tags: java, android

I have a heavy task to be executed when a button is pressed. The UI got blocked when button clicked while the task is been executed.

I want to show a progressbar with the progress of a task.

How can I do that?

Thanks

EDIT: I fixed this using AsyncTask with a progressdialog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **AsyncTask**

Example :

```
 private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

      @Override
      protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            // Put Your Code Here Which is to be executed on button Click
            return "Executed";
      }      

      @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // Dismiss Progress Dialog here
      }

      @Override
      protected void onPreExecute() {
      // Show Progress Dialog Here 

      }

}
```

And on Button Click Execute :

```
     new LongOperation.execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

In order for the UI not to get blocked, you can use a separate thread to run your 'heavy task' in it. The best way is to take a look in [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). Take a look at the documentation and when you get to "The 4 Steps" section, in the first step you will read:

> onPreExecute(), invoked on the UI thread before the task is executed.
>   This step is normally used to setup the task, for instance by showing
>   a progress bar in the user interface.

[Here's a tutorial](https://sites.google.com/site/androidhowto/how-to-1/create-a-custom-progress-bar-using-asynctask) how to do that. 
Keep in mind AsyncTask is not the only solution, there's other tools for handling 'heavy tasks' in the background - see this [excellent article](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html) on the subject (also with code samples).